# How to open a .p file with fopen in Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, file

I have an third-party file with the extension .p and I try if it is possible to open it using the function `fopen`:

```
fopen(title.p)
```

This returns 3, which is a file identifier according to the help function:

> help fopen
>
> fopen - Open file, or obtain information about open files
>
> This MATLAB function opens the file, filename, for binary read access, and returns an integer file identifier equal to or greater than 3.

What should I do to see (if possible) the content of the file?

Comment: Put apostrophes around the filename: `fid = fopen('title.p')`. To actually read it, use another function (probably `textscan`) with `textscan(fid)` or `fgetl(fid)`

Comment: See MATLAB's documentation for [data import and export](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/data-import-and-export.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A file with the extension `.p` in the context of matlab probably refers to a [pcode](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pcode.html) file. It is obfuscated bytecode, you won't be able to read anything useful. Nevertheless you can run the function calling it like any other matlab function.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to open the file using

```
fid = fopen('file.p')
fgetl(fid)
```

However, the content was not useful, indeed.